# SSIS XML Source: XML Content and XSD Content through variables

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to pass XML File and XSD File data through SSIS Variables.
In XML Source component I am able to select XML data from variable.
Afterwards how to keep XSD Script in a SSIS Variable? 
Is it possible to do in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

`1. Create the variable`

`2. In the properties of the data flow task where you are using the xml file go to expressions`

`3. Create an expression for the [<Component>].[XMLSchemaDefinition]`

`4. In the expression builder use your variable`

That should be about it

Comment: @T I: Thanks for prompt reply. But i tried that.  That Expression taking only path of XSD, Not XSD Script. 
I want to store XSD Script.